# looking for opensource 2 factor authentication server

Tags: authentication, two-factor

i'm looking for opensource 2 factor authentication service. (Right now we're using openLDAP.)

We're just using Linux Servers. That's why the service should work well with PAM Linux.

It would also be nice to have 2 factor authentication support for Dell's iDrac and Cisco.

Thanks in advance for any links :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenOTP](http://rcdevs.com/products/openotp/) is a solution.

Comment: i will take your answer as the correct one, **although the core componenent (otp-server) isn't opensource**... but this server has a lot of features... thank you for this great link! :-)

Comment: No problem.  I looked into this briefly, but never implemented it here.  It'd be interesting to see if you could utilize this solution with Windows Logon... probably by "side-loading" a module into AD.

Answer (score 3):

[Google Authenticator](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/wiki/PamModuleInstructions) can be installed as a PAM module. We've had good results with it. The smartphone apps are free and open source, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Still looking?

[privacyidea](https://github.com/privacyidea/privacyidea) is the open source solution. It is a fork of LinOTP. 
privacyidea is hosted at github, discussed at github and issues are kept at github to give you best transparency.

Answer (score 1):

[Duosecurity](http://www.duosecurity.com/) provides a two-factor authentication service. It works with mobiles phones as hardware token, but it seems that you can't run your own server.

If I remember correctly, the client-side is opensource. It works with pam, juniper and cisco's ssl vpn, and others.

I liked a lot the push request on the phone with their android/iphone app :)

Answer (score 1):

We have an open-source two-factor authentication option: http://www.wikidsystems.com/community-version

enjoy,